# Open PDF file contained in the URL

Tags: iphone, ipad, pdf

I have a link that contains a downloadable pdf file. This link doesn't have its extension as .pdf, its  just a normal link. Its a web-service where i pass "PDF" as a parameter that returns me a PDF file. Whenever I open such link on a desktop browser, it directly ask for downloading the pdf. Into my ipad app, i need to display such pdf in a web view. What can be the possible solution?

Comment: For some reasons, I can't share the link. Lets say the link ends with like myservice?outputType=PDF

Answer (score 0):

You should make a url request and load that in to a Webview like this,

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

[webView loadRequest:request];
```

The url is your link to the PDF file and webview is UIWebView object where you can view the PDF.